# Python script not responding for large volume Cassandra queries

Tags: python, cassandra, limit

When I ran the python script for getting the data from Cassandra using

> SELECT * FROM my_keyspace LIMIT 5000000;

using a limit of 5 million, then the records are shown up after a processing time of 22 minutes. But when I set the limit to 10 million records and fire the query, the script keeps waiting for a very long time and I am yet to receive a response. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify partition key in you query so coordinator node should request all nodes to get data. Also the coordinator will collect all millions rows before pass result to you python script  and it can cause a lot of garbage collection invocations on the coordinator.

You should avoid queries without partition keys to don't have performance issues.

Please check out [Cassandra Read Path](https://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/ReadPathForUsers) for more details.